# Sign in to multiple Microsoft account in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, live-sdk

Is it possible to:

- sign-in to multiple Microsoft accounts in a Windows Store app? Mail app does it*
- sign-in to Microsoft account that is not the one used for logging in to Windows? Store app does it*

I tried something like the following (taken from Live SDK sample code) but it only sign me in with the account I used to log in to Windows

```
var client = new LiveAuthClient();
var result = await client.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });

if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    this.AddAccountButton.Content = "connected";
}
```

Appreciate any help.

---

* I'm not sure if the built-in apps use different API's to do this

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, I've been told that's not possible, here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693836/login-with-microsoft-account-using-live-sdk/26697592#26697592)
I found out, that if the user use the Windows with a Microsoft account, there is no possibilities for multiple accounts. But in case of a local account, you can implement a signing off logic to your app, and it won't log you in automatically.